# How to open product tab on click of link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a particular tab on a webpage to open when a link is clicked. Not only that, I need the page to scroll down to that area once it's clicked too (like an anchor tag).

Here's the page I'm working on:

http://www.lifestyleclotheslines.com.au/hills-portable-170-clothesline/

The link I'm working on is the blue '154 reviews' link next to the gold stars under the product title. When this is clicked, I need it to open the 'Reviews (140)' tab further below, and also scroll down to that area.

Here's what I currently have wrapped around the link:

```
<a onclick="ActiveProductTab('ProductReviews_Tab'); window.scrollTo(0,jQuery('#ProductReviews').offset().top); return false; ">154 reviews</a>
```

It's not working at all, nothing happens when I click.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<a onclick="$('#ReviewsTabLink').click();
$('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#ReviewsTabLink').offset().top + 'px'
        }, 'fast'); ">154 reviews</a>
```

It work on your site. I tested now.

Comment: works perfectly! You even added the animate as well which was a bonus! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The review tab header has the id `ReviewsTabLink`, so you can manually trigger a click event(since I'm not seeing any plugin that is used for the tab - if you have used any plugin for the tab you can look at its documentation to see if there is an option to set the active tab like the [active option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) in [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/))

```
jQuery('#ReviewsTabLink').click()
```